# Does elevator apply a force on a person when accelerating upwards?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration

When a person is in the elevator and the elevator is accelerating upwards, the normal force is greater than the force of gravity, but is this because the elevator applies a force on the person when accelerating upwards?

Answer (score 0):

Yes when it is accelerating Upwards against gravity but If the elevator is moving upward at a constant speed then it’s no different than standing on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a normal force acting on the person in the elevator, whether the elevator is going up or going down, it is the force acting on the person due to the elevator.

Hope it helps.